# Google visualization chart on server side c#

Tags: c#, google-visualization

I need to export the geo chart generated using google visualization into an image.
One way is to go to the client side, generated and render the geo chart and then use getImageURI() and using the result generates an image on the server side.

But, is there a way that I can skip going to the client side as I don't really need a chart to be created in the browser. Is there something I can do directly on the server side?

Is there a way of generating the chart on server side and get the image data?

Comment: Purely from the server side I'm not sure you could do it, but you can try to create a background service with this library: https://github.com/AlexSanseau/Web.Screenshot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [server side browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692132/server-side-browser)